# Aurelia I18N: Scan html sources for new keys and update translation.json files

Tags: aurelia, i18next

Is there any tool to scan aurelia project sources (html, js) files and create (update) keys in `translation.json` files?

Especially I want to collect keys from HTML files that use `TBindingBehavior` and `TValueConverter` translation style.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** The packages suggested, are developed by my employer company.

Following are main steps involved in this process.

1. Generating i18n keys for the html templates, using [gulp-i18n-update-localization-ids](https://github.com/Netatwork-de/gulp-i18n-update-localization-ids)
2. Extract keys and values to an external resource, using [gulp-i18n-extract](https://github.com/Netatwork-de/gulp-i18n-extract)
3. Manually translate the values for different languages
4. Compile the translations to generate locale files for different language, using [gulp-i18n-compile2](https://github.com/Netatwork-de/gulp-i18n-compile2)

Following are the minimalistic gulp tasks

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const path = require("path");
const updateLocalizationIds = require('gulp-i18n-update-localization-ids');
const i18nExtract = require('gulp-i18n-extract');
const i18nCompile = require('gulp-i18n-compile2');

const src = path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    json = path.resolve(src, "*.r.json"),
    html = path.resolve(src, "*.html"),
    translations = path.resolve(__dirname, "translations/i18n.json"),
    locales = path.resolve(__dirname, "locales"),
    i18nGlobalPrefixes = new Map();

const generateI18nKeys = function () {
    return gulp.src(html)
        .pipe(updateLocalizationIds({
            emit: 'onChangeOnly',
            ignore: [{ content: v => v.startsWith('${') && v.endsWith('}') }],
            idTemplate: updateLocalizationIds.prefixFilename(i18nGlobalPrefixes),
            whitelist: [
                { tagName: 'h2' },
                {
                    tagName: 'another-custom-el',
                    attrs: ['some-other-value1', 'some-other-value2']
                }
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(src));
}

const i18nExtractOptions = {
    plugIns: [
        new i18nExtract.html(),
        new i18nExtract.json()
    ],
    markUpdates: true,
    defaultLanguages: ['de', "fr"] // add more language here as per your need
};

const extractI18n = function () {
    return gulp.src([html, json])
        .pipe(i18nExtract.extract(translations, i18nExtractOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
}

const compileOptions = {
    fileName: "translation.json",
    defaultLanguage: "en"
};

const compileI18n = function () {
    return gulp.src(translations)
        .pipe(i18nCompile(compileOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(locales));
}

gulp.task("i18n", gulp.series(generateI18nKeys, extractI18n, compileI18n));
```

#### What's happening here?

Let us assume that you have all the html files under `src` directory. You can also have some plain json files under `src` that act as external resources. Though it is not really needed, in this example, I have used the extension `*.r.json` for that (`r` indicates resource).

The **first task `generateI18nKeys`** generates i18n keys for the html templates. For example, it transforms the following `edit.html`
...

```html
<!--edit.html-->
<h2>some text</h2>
<another-custom-el some-other-value1="value1" some-other-value2="value2"></another-custom-el>
```

... to the following

```html
<!--edit.html-->
<h2 t="edit.t0">some text</h2>
<another-custom-el some-other-value1="value1" some-other-value2="value2"
  t="[some-other-value1]edit.t1;[some-other-value2]edit.t2"></another-custom-el>
```

Use the `whitelist` property in the config option for this task, to mark elements and attributes for the key generation target.

In **the next step**, the keys and the corresponding values are extracted to a json file which looks like as follows.

```
{
  "edit": {
    "content": {
      "edit.t0": {
        "content": "some text",
        "lastModified": "2019-05-26T16:23:42.306Z",
        "needsUpdate": true,
        "translations": {
          "de": {
            "content": "",
            "lastModified": ""
          },
          "fr": {
            "content": "",
            "lastModified": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "edit.t1": {
        "content": "value1",
        "lastModified": "2019-05-26T16:23:42.306Z",
        "needsUpdate": true,
        "translations": {
          "de": {
            "content": "",
            "lastModified": ""
          },
          "fr": {
            "content": "",
            "lastModified": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "edit.t2": {
        "content": "value2",
        "lastModified": "2019-05-26T16:23:42.306Z",
        "needsUpdate": true,
        "translations": {
          "de": {
            "content": "",
            "lastModified": ""
          },
          "fr": {
            "content": "",
            "lastModified": ""
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "src": "src\\edit.html"
  }
}
```

Note that empty contents are generated for the localeIds, specified in the task. You can manually change this file to add translations for every language, configured.

**Lastly, the `compileI18n` task** generates files for every language from the last json, that looks something like below.

```
{
  "edit": {
    "t0": "some text",
    "t1": "value1",
    "t2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Note that this file can directly be consumed by the aurelia-i18n plugin. For more details check the package specific documentation.

Hope this helps.